# Enable comment mirroring option not shown?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using this code to get comments from users but I don't know why I don't see enable mirroring option in setting any help would be appreciated.thanks

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="test.html" data-numposts="5"></div>


</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11&appId=My-id';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I don't know why I don't see enable mirroring option in setting

Because Facebook is removing Comment Mirroring again.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/:

> Comment Mirroring: Pages that currently have Comment Mirroring enabled will continue to mirror comments for the next 90 days. Full deprecation of Comment Mirroring will conclude on 2/6/2018. Comment Mirroring is no longer available for Pages that do not have it enabled already.